# Every subgroup of finite index contained in an infinite group $G$ contains a normal subgroup of $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H<G$ such that $H$ has finite index in the infinite group $G$. Then $G$ contains a normal subgroup of finite index contained in $H$.

Can I create a subgroup of index $2$ in $G$ using elements of $H$?

Comment: There are infinite groups with finite index subgroups but no index $2$ subgroup. For instance, $\mathbb{Z}_3$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: say $[G:H] = n$, i.e. the set of left cosets $G/H$ has $n$ elements. Define an action of $G$ on $G/H$ by left translation. This induces a homomorphism from $G$ into the symmetric group on $G/H$ (which is isomorphic to $S_{n}$). What can you say about the kernel of this homomorphism?

Comment: I haven't learned about group actions or kernels yet (next two chapters) and don't want to jump the gun. Is there a more elementary way of proving this? The question comes from M.A. Armstrong's book *Groups & Symmetry*, question 15.11.